# Buffalo questions off topic?

Tags: support

Will a buffalo question be allowed in a pet question because I own a buffalo and I have many questions about it?

Comment: While I appreciate you own one, I suspect that a lot of their care is going to be based on the fact that they are a farm animal and not really something intended to be a pet, regardless of how you consider it yourself.

Comment: ok thanks for your answer

Comment: If you frame the questions correctly, you might gain more knowledge posting at [Sustainability](http://sustainability.stackexchange.com/), see related [Animal Husbandry](http://meta.pets.stackexchange.com/questions/1987)

Comment: I cannot see how sustainability would help with this quesiton

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We have allowed questions on other "livestock" type animals in the past, notably chickens and llamas, when they're specifically pets as opposed to stock for commercial purposes. So, on that basis, the answer is that you can ask.

However, I really suspect that you will not get much in the way of useful answers from a site like this one. Highly unusual pets, like this clearly would be, are not something most, if not all, site members are going to be in a position to answer questions about. So I think you'll be creating a lot of answerless questions as a result. Still, you're quite free to try, you never know...

Comment: Buffalo (if he means Bison), is so closely related to domestic cattle that their care requirements are similar. Not super complicated.

Comment: I can see how it would be not about pets thanks.